# Can't Pin Applications to Start Menu in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, icons, start-menu

When I try to pin apps to the start menu it looks like this:

[image]

I don't really know why it's happening and all my old pinned apps still work even when I remove them and try to pin them again.

What I tried.

- Moving the shortcuts into the start menu directory
- Upgrading Windows
- Sfc Scan / restore health

Sadly nothings works, does someone know how to fix it?

**Edit:**

`layout.xml` File:

https://pastebin.com/mV8MbX2A

Comment: I've seen that "W~" before too and I vaguely recall is being something about the XML file related to the start menu layout. Run the command `Export-StartLayout -UseDesktopApplicationID -Path layout.xml` but maybe use `C:\folder\layout.xml` so you know the exact folder it will go to, and then once that file is created, open it with notepad, and then [edit] the question and put it in there too. Here's a related post https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/configuration/customize-and-export-start-layout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't Pin Some Applications to Start Menu in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/947985/cant-pin-some-applications-to-start-menu-in-windows-10)

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT added to my post.

Comment: @Guest. Nope, nothing there worked for me. it's a different problem.